# Why does the variable declared outside paint() is not recognized inside paint()?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

Why does `arraylist.get(0)` report an error when running. I get no error when compiling but when i run it, it runs perfectly but it gives:

`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0`

and the program reports the error is in the line where `arraylist.get(0)` is implemented. I declared `arraylist` outside paint() and it gives the error above. But when I declare it inside paint(), no error is reported. However, I want to declare `arraylist` outside.

How can I declare `arraylist` outside paint();?

here's my code below:

```
class Game{

int x=0, y=250;
String line;
String[] list;
static  ArrayList<String> arraylist;

public static void main(String[] args){

    Game game= new Game();
    game.read();

}

public void read(){

arraylist= new ArrayList<String>();

    try{

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("dictionary.txt"));
        line= br.readLine();
        list= line.split(" ");

        for(int i=0; i<list.length ;i++)
            arraylist.add(list[i]);

        Collections.shuffle(arraylist);

    }
    catch(Exception e){}
}

public void paint(Graphics g){

    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2= (Graphics2D)g;
    Font font= new Font("Impact",Font.PLAIN,10);
    g2.setFont(font);
    g2.drawString(arraylist.get(0),x,y);

    try{
        Thread.sleep(50);
    }
    catch(Exception e){}

    repaint();

}
}
```

update: edited the code

Comment: Well your List is empty. Perhaps you can show us how you attempt to fill it. Also, `Thread.sleep(50);...repaint();` don't do this inside paint!!! Use a timer. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html

Comment: Can you please provide contents of `decripted.txt` file ?

Comment: @atishshimpi the contents doesnt matter. it just contains words separated by a space. getting word by word when parsing

Comment: yes I have tried by using sample file with contents separated by space on your code and it's working fine.

Comment: thanks for the answer bros, i got it running just now with no errors. i just put the filereader code in main() and made all variables of the code static

Comment: Making things static isn't the correct solution. NB You can't sleep in a paint() method. You need to use the `SwingTimer` to achedule your repaints.

Answer (score 0):

Paint is called in UI Thread several times before anything added to the `arraylist`. 
You can simply check if it's not null and have at list one item inside it.

Comment: ok lol. thanks for the answer, i got it running just now with no errors. i just put the filereader code in `main()` and made all variables of the code `static`.

Comment: @yologaming :-) In that way you filled the array list before UI Thread gets started, basically the same idea.